# LED lights on pin 1 but it fails on other pins

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, led

Hi i am new to this raspberry pi. I am trying to light up LED it works fine on pin 1 with 3.3V.
then I am trying to use pin7 and pin11 both but it fails to light.
I already checked the GIPO setup for python and circuit both many times....

```
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ## Import GPIO Library
 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use BOARD pin numbering
 GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT) ## Setup GPIO pin 7 to OUT
 GPIO.output(7, True) ## Turn on GPIO pin 7
 GPIO.cleanup()
```

I think there must be some problem with my LED or resistance I am using 160ohm resistance.

pls help with this...will this resistance work with LED and GPIO pins voltage...

thanks in advance....

Comment: GPIO voltage is also 3.3 volt, so the led should light up. Could you post a picture of how you connected it?

Comment: The voltage for LEDs vary, though most draw abotu 0.2A in current - for example, if it is a Red or Yellow LED, you might blow it up due to too much voltage - for info, see [this page](http://www.retrospieler.de/e-led-r.html)

Comment: Hi @Gerben i think my circuit is good because LED lights up  in pin1 there is only issue with GPIO pins.Does this 160ohm resistance works to light up LED in GPIO pins (any color LED)

Comment: @Wilf so what should i have to do to achieve this much current...i am new to this current and voltage...
can u pls help??

Comment: I have a feeling the GPIOs may be being turned off when the script exits, but I don't have a Pi to hand to test and usually do a manual cleanup when I expect scripts to exit.

Comment: Dan is correct. GPIO pins return to input once the script exits. Try adding a delay at the end of the code. At the top: `import time` and at the bottom `time.sleep(10)`

Comment: 160 Ohm is more than enough if powering from 3.3V. The led would have to have a forward voltage drop of less than 0.1V to exceed 20mA. Red leds have the lowest drop at around 1.8V. A 1.8V drop at 3.3V with a 160 Ohm resistor will result in around 10mA.

Comment: at the end of my code i have GPIO.cleanup() this..
Is this could be the reason behind the GPIO pins return to input??? @Gerben

Comment: @manankhh Adding the ```time.sleep(10)``` before the ```GPIO.cleanup()``` should work. ```cleanup()``` is essentially a way of resetting the GPIOs after you are done using them.

Comment: Also try the interactive python prompt `sudo python` and type in this script one line at a time, then you'll see the LED light up as soon as you call `GPIO.output(7, True)`

Comment: Yes, sorry. You need to put the sleep before cleanup. If I remember correctly cleanup is called automatically before the python script exits.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the LEDs are oriented correctly. LEDs (Light Emitting **Diodes**) only allow current through one way. Try flipping them.

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup pin11 as well so your modified code would be:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ## Import GPIO Library
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use BOARD pin numbering
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT) ## Setup GPIO pin 7 to OUT
GPIO.output(7, True) ## Turn on GPIO pin 7
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT) ## Setup GPIO 11 to OUT
GPIO.output(11, False) ## Set GPIO 11 to False
```

Comment: I doubt this is the issue, OP claims neither pin 7 or 11 work and that the LED only works when connected the 3.3v